# If/else loop to check image height Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I used this code to hide the bottom 37 pixels on the clients request, it hides the bottom of all blogpost images (it's a copyright mark), but now she wants to add larger images as well, which does't have the copyright mark at the bottom, so it must display in full, the size of the larger images is 1843px, and the small images are 351px in height.

Bascially I have to check "if container image greater than 351px", hide the bottom border, else, display image in full height.

However, If I add the code below in a normal loop, it doesn't work.

```
  $('.image_Container').each(function() {
    *var $this = $(this),
       w = $this.find('img').width(), // Width of the image inside .box
       h = $this.find('img').height() - 37; // Height of the image inside                 container

     $this.width(w).height(h); // Applies the changes to the images
  });
```

Any idea on how to make it work in a loop?

Comment: try `$(this).next("img").height();` and `$(this).next("img").width();` to get height and width and reassign .... may work not sure

Comment: Is it because you've got star(*) in front of your variable definition? `*var $this`